# Visual Basic Graphics updating error, Only update on user input

Tags: vb.net, graphics

I have been working on a simple program that uses pictureboxes and draws a grid on the form.

However when the program starts, it leave a transparent box where my picturebox should be.

Seen below:

[image: Transparent box in form]

The only code I have in the paint event is:

```
Private Sub pb_key_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles pb_key.Paint
    pb_key.Image = keyBMP
End Sub
```

Where keyBMP is just simply, a white rectangle that is meant to be in that empty transparent hole.

Thanks

NOTES:
I have tried doing Me.Refresh() in the form load handler but alas no white box

Comment: I think that you should not set the Image property in the paint event because it causes the Paint event to fire again which sets the image property, which causes the paint event to fire again, over and over.  I'm surprised you're not getting a stack overflow exception.  In general you should not do anything in the Paint event that would cause the control to refresh.  Set that property outside the paint event and then call `pb_key.Refresh()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was given to me by a comment:

I think that you should not set the Image property in the paint event because it causes the Paint event to fire again which sets the image property, which causes the paint event to fire again, over and over. I'm surprised you're not getting a stack overflow exception. In general you should not do anything in the Paint event that would cause the control to refresh. Set that property outside the paint event and then call pb_key.Refresh() – @ChrisDunaway